# Why can I not declare a function before I declare its contents? (c++)

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have this program that adds powers of numbers and for some reason it keeps throwing an error at me when I run it, the program runs fine if I declare and define the contents before the main function but I don't understand why that's necessary... Here's the code that's giving me problems:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

long long addPow(int n, int p);

int main() {
    cout << addPow(100, 1) * addPow(100, 1) - addPow(100, 2) << endl;
    return 0;
}

addPow(int n, int p) {
    long long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += pow(i, p);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

changing it to this fixes it all, but I don't really know why...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

long long addPow(int n, int p) {
    long long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += pow(i, p);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    cout << addPow(100, 1) * addPow(100, 1) - addPow(100, 2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If someone could help me out I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: You forgot the return type: `long long addPow(int n, int p) {...}`

Comment: It is because of stuff like `addPow(int n, int p)` and it's evil twin `double addPow(double n, double p)` That I don't like forward declarations unless I have to use them.  If you change the prototype of one, be it a type change or even just a typo fix, you have to change the other. Miss one and you'll get a compiler error  that makes no sense because you're looking right at it and it's right, or a linker error that makes no sense because you're looking at the other declaration and it's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function in the first code block, defined as

```
addPow(int n, int p) {
```

needs the extra information (namely the return type) you put into the prototype. It should look like this:

```
long long addPow(int n, int p) {
```

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much! That was a dumb mistake to be honest. I'll definitely remember that lol